# Implement Javascript Code in the footer if user is logged in

Tags: permissions

I want to implement the below javascript and php code to footer if user is logged in.

```
<script>
  window.intercomSettings = {
    app_id: "fbpqr48f",
    name: <?php echo do_shortcode('[IMS_username]');?>, // Full name
    email: <?php echo do_shortcode('[IMS_useremail]');?>, // Email address
    created_at: <?php echo do_shortcode('[IMS_userregdate]');?>, // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
  };
  </script>
<script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/fbpqr48f';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>
```

I know I can use is_user_logged_in() but it I don't know or not getting idea that how I can use echo inside echo as you can see the script code has already 3 echo used to implement the shortcode.

```
 <?php  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'I can paste the code here';
} else {
    echo ''; 
}

?>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to echo your script code you can tell your footer.php file to proceed with JavaScript with `if` statement if user is logged in:

```
<?php  if ( is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
    // Your JavaScript code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ok let me check it.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer, using the [`edit`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/283217/edit) link above and explain what this code snippet does and how it would solve the original problem? The more details and references to things such as [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) or [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) provides greater information to future readers than just the code snippet by itself.